# What kind of object is needed as first argument in mutagen.mp4.MP4Cover?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp3, albumart, mutagen

I would like to use the function `mutagen.mp4.MP4Cover(data, imageformat)` ([direct link to documentation](http://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mp4.html?highlight=MP4Cover#mutagen.mp4.MP4Cover)), however the documentation only specifies `imageformat`, but not what `data` is.

I have a `.png` file that I would like to add to an `.mp3` as cover/album art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I have a .png file that I would like to add to an .mp3 as cover/album art."*

Is this MP3 data actually contained inside an MP4 or M4A format file? If not, then you cannot use `.mp4.MP4Cover` since the header of MP3 file does have any "slot" to insert some cover art. Containers like MP4 & M4A have a specific place built-in for adding cover (the `covr` atom).

For a stand-alone MP3 file you must instead add [**ID3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) metadata.
 
Specfically you want to add a tag called `APIC` (Attached PIC) :

```
from mutagen import id3, mp3
file = mp3.MP3('test.mp3')

imagedata = open('cover.png', 'rb').read()
file.tags.add(id3.APIC(3, 'image/png', 3, 'Front cover', imagedata))
file.save()
```

Comment: PS: I don't use Mutagen but I know MP3 & MP4 bytes so if the above code isn't wrking let me know of any errors. From research that code seemed as easiest example to share / test.

Comment: Thank you I have figured out in the meantime that I was wrong with my approach and have solved the issue the same way you propose here.